# How to run selenium test cases on a Digital Ocean Ubuntu server?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, digital-ocean

I am running my selenium test cases on a local machine using `maven`. But when I'm running the code on on my `digitalocean` Ubuntu server it is failing. I set the path of chromedriver but I'm getting the following error:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running TestSuite
Configuring TestNG with: TestNG652Configurator
Starting ChromeDriver 2.27.440175 (9bc1d90b8bfa4dd181fbbf769a5eb5e575574320) on port 25251
Only local connections are allowed.
May 17, 2017 6:16:28 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Attempting bi-dialect session, assuming Postel's Law holds true on the remote end
May 17, 2017 6:17:29 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
Configuring TestNG with: TestNG652Configurator
Tests run: 5, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 3, Time elapsed: 63.412 sec <<< FAILURE! - in TestSuite
invokeBrowser(datum.LoginTest)  Time elapsed: 62.986 sec  <<< FAILURE!
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: no such session
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.27.440175 (9bc1d90b8bfa4dd181fbbf769a5eb5e575574320),platform=Linux 4.4.0-71-generic x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 77 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.0.1', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:49:13 -0700'
System info: host: 'devopspipe', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.4.0-71-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{message=unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.27.440175 (9bc1d90b8bfa4dd181fbbf769a5eb5e575574320),platform=Linux 4.4.0-71-generic x86_64), platform=ANY}]
Session ID: 513bf4635a1df42b52f11a16938c3b9d
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:216)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:168)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:635)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:658)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver$RemoteWebDriverOptions$RemoteWindow.maximize(RemoteWebDriver.java:882)
    at datum.UtilsMethods.browserInvoke(UtilsMethods.java:77)
    at datum.LoginTest.invokeBrowser(LoginTest.java:19)


Results :

Failed tests: 
  LoginTest.invokeBrowser:19 » NoSuchSession no such session
  (Driver info: chr...

Tests run: 5, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 3

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 01:10 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-05-17T06:17:30+00:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 19M/46M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.17:test (default-test) on project DataVisualisation: There are test failures.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to /home/sample-selenium-datum/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Comment: I think the error on the console says it all `error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally`. Does your Chrome starts up with normal config without using `TestNG652Configurator`? Thanks

Comment: Have you read the help on the ChromeDriver website? Is Chrome installed in the default location? Have you tried using ChromeOptions to set the binary location? Have you tried using the latest versions of Selenium, ChromeDriver, and Chrome?

Comment: @MarkLapierre yes I have tried with latest version of selenium and google chrome .